# Publishing Post on Facebook C# Sdk ,Desktop Application

Tags: c#, winforms

I am confused about publishing a post on facebook using C# sdk

I want to publish Name ,Description and photo on my page:

- Do i need "publish_actions " in "items in review"(permissions)? because it is my own page .
- When i try to add publish_actions ,facebook asks for privacy policy url ,How am i supposed to make it using C# Desktop Application, I didn't Found useful help on google.

**Settings:**

I have added `http: //localhost:80/` to my site URL and:

```
 http://abbasnaqvi512.tumblr.com/ to Valid OAuth redirect URIs.
 Native or desktop app?=Yes
 Is your App Secret embedded?=No
 Client OAuth Login=yes
 Embedded browser OAuth Login=NO
 App Secret Proof for Server API calls=No
 Require 2-factor reauthorization=No
```

[image]

```
  private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Url.OriginalString.Contains("assets") && e.Url.OriginalString.Contains("code"))
            {
                 code = Regex.Matches(e.Url.OriginalString, "assets.tumblr.com.*?code%3D(?<data>.*?)&")[0].Groups["data"].Value;
                richTextBox1.Text += "\n\n" + code + "\n\n";
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(code) == false)
                {
                    webBrowser1.Stop();
                    webBrowser1.Dispose();
                    ShareOnFB();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }



    private void ShareOnFB()
    {
        string pageId = "ABC";

        FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(code);

        dynamic messagePost = new ExpandoObject();
        messagePost.access_token = code;
        messagePost.picture = "http://fc02.ostadreza-d6pkzrd.jpg";
        // messagePost.link = "http://www.examplearticle.com";
        messagePost.name = "NAME";
        messagePost.description = "DESCRIPTION";

        var result = client.Post(string.Format("/{0}/feed", pageId), messagePost);
        richTextBox1.Text += "\n\n"+result+"\n\n";
    }
```

Rightnow it is giving me  Error

```
         "Malformed access token AQA44CIJCyoV7_Xlz3mtvdPErPBrmtF6ykz6teCc9QINrfePHxEOiQKIyl8wgxH1mvQxEtLE-xnVfdyfiE38eA2M1YU7RS22MNIKNUh5wMmd2zwPCLj30PiEaq6CKIfcq9yIvq_slblOWmE4LYcynyH_pJuZcPc3EqLCQoCUBtSO58X1WtiohRoRvq70QWHpZec-7jhzUQnW75nlk4wpEwcJ9yOcBlPbne72sV6yX_hqndI5RKVDjqRJzdOscOblbLCkC1xtI0rMD1bCJufvpAa-tMsIyG6ATqrk6TNqXXASlcvialbzh0WttS2x-j_J59LF7cBh22T18P8qOly5cOwF"
```

Thanks for reading my question ,Kindly help me,

**Update:** I have added publish_actions in review by adding tumblr privacy policy url ,Notes and screen shots of my application ,It is on review